# R package build, reason for "object 'xxx' not found"

Tags: r, foreach, roxygen2

I'm attempting to build an R package from code that works outside a package.  My first try and it is rather complex, nested functions that end up doing parallel processing using doMPI and foreach.  Also using RStudio 1.01.43 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I build the package and works ok.  Then when I try to run the top level function which calls the next it throws an error:

```
Error in { : task 6 failed - "object 'RunOys' not found"
```

I'm setting the boolean variable RunOys=TRUE manually before calling the top level function, when it gets down to the one where this variable is called for an ifelse statement it fails.  Before I call the top level function I check the globalenv() and

```
> RunOys
[1] TRUE
```

In the foreach parallel code I have this statement, which works find until compiled into an R package:

```
FinalCalcs <- function (...) {
    results <- data.frame ( foreach::`%dopar%`(
             foreach::`%:%`(foreach::foreach(j = 1:NumSim, .combine = acomb,
                                             .options.mpi=opts1),
                            foreach::foreach (i = 1:PopSize, .combine=rbind,
                                    .options.mpi=opts2,
                                    .export = c(ls(globalenv())),
                                    .packages = c("zoo", "msm", "FAdist", "qmra"))),
                            {
```

which should export all of the objects in globalenv() to each slave.

I can't understand why some variables seem to get passed and not other.  Do I need to specify it explicitly as a @param in the file for the function where it is called?

Comment: If you want to be super dirty, try with `.export = c(ls(globalenv(), ls(environment()), ls(parent.frame()))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `foreach`, the better is to have all the needed variables present in the same environment where `foreach` is called. So basically, I always use `foreach` inside a function and pass all the variables that are needed in the `foreach` to this function.

Do as if `foreach` couldn't see past its calling function. You won't need to export anything. For functions, use `package::function` (like in packages so that you don't need to `@import` packages).

Comment: Might you know of a small example of this?  This model requires about 60 parameter values an is likely to increase.  I also want all parameter values to have a default but be able to change any or all of them at time of calling the top level function.  Thx

Comment: 60 parameters is not reasonable for a function. Can you factorize them in e.g. lists ?

Comment: I could certainly cat them into lists, one for each function.  Could I then use those as arguments for the top level function?